# I am trying to find particular data (first and last row from specific column) from csv file in lua

Tags: lua

for example this is output from my csv file

```
10, 172.119140625, 302.734375, 20.117189407349, 11.035157203674, 33.3, 3491.6999511719, 
20, 172.119140625, 302.1240234375, 20.117189407349, 11.132813453674, 33.3, 3462.5534667969, 
30, 173.33984375, 302.1240234375, 20.312501907349, 11.132813453674, 33.2, 3471.3747558594,
```

I need 1st and last row data from specific column from (unknown number of rows) big file

I have tried

```
local contents = file:read( "*all" )
print( contents )
```

I got all data from file. But I need specific data. Please anyone help.

Comment: any ideas? this is not a coding service.

Comment: hint: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html   generic for, file:lines(), string.gmatch

Comment: Try `io.lines(filename)`